# Python 3 - How to update dictionary to have multiple values in one key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
employeenum = int(input("How many employees? "))
employee ={}
namelist = []
salarylist = []
jobname = []
profile = []
for i in range (0,employeenum):
    job1 = input("Please enter the job's name here: ").lower()
    name1 = input("Please enter the employee's name here: ")
    salary1 = int(input("Please enter the employee's salary here: "))
    jobname.append(job1)
    print(jobname)
    namelist.append(name1)
    salarylist.append(salary1)
    profile.append([{'Name': namelist[i], 'Salary': salarylist[i]}])
    employee.update({jobname[i]: profile[i]})
    employee[jobname[i]].append(profile[i])
    print(employee)
    print(profile)
print(employee)
# {'Programmer': [{'Name': 'Tim', 'Salary': 65000}, {'Name': 'Sally', 'Salary': 50500}], 'Part Time Manager': [{'Name': 'Bob', 'Salary': 17500}]}
```

Hi All, I have a problem with my code as I am trying to print a dictionary that will be keyed by the job name of a worker and the values will be their name and salary (The desired output is the last comment line in the code above). I am running into a problem where if two or more person has the same job, it will overwrite the previous person's profile. So for say if John and Nick are both nurses, only Nick's profile will show up because he was the last input by the user. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have a look into `defaultdict`. Set the default as a `list` and just `append` the values against a key.

Comment: @roganjosh Is there any other way except defaultdict to do this?

Comment: Yes, check whether a value exists already. If it does, store the existing value, appending the existing value to the new empty list you assign against the key, then appaend the new value. On the 3rd time you encounter the same key, check whether there is a list stored against the key and handle appropriately. Why are you avoiding `defaultdict`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following or alternatively you could look at `defaultdict`:

```
employeenum = int(input("How many employees? "))
employee ={}

for i in range (0, employeenum):

    job1 = input("Please enter the job's name here: ").lower()
    name1 = input("Please enter the employee's name here: ")
    salary1 = int(input("Please enter the employee's salary here: "))

    new_entry = {"Name": name1, "Salary": salary1}
    if job1 in employee:
        employee[job1].append(new_entry)
    else:
        employee[job1] = [new_entry]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
employee = dict()
for i in range(int(input("How Many Employees?"))):
    title = input("Please enter the job's name here: ").lower()
    data = {'Name': input("Please enter the employee's name here: "),
            'Salary': int(input("Please enter the employee's salary here: "))}
    try:
        employee[title].append(data)
    except KeyError:
        employee[title] = [data]
    print(title + ": " + str(data))
print(employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that a dictionary can only return a single object, but that object could be an array.

- Set the dictionary to return a list of employee records.  You can do this either using meow's comment above.
- Find something unique to store and return, like an employee number or job id.  You might have one dictionary of employee records, looked up by number, and your current dictionary taking finding all employees with that job id.  That is, the value of the first dictionary can be a list of keys to look up in a second dictionary.
- The exact answer depends on what you are trying to do.  You should decide if a title like 'Programmer' can have two different 'John Smith' people working on it.  If this is a salary comparison tool, John might have two part time jobs with two salaries but you want to include his PhD in English Literature in one place.

Figuring out the right way to structure data is about half the daily work of professional computer programmers.  Don't give up!